# CentOS routing between multiple subnet

Tags: linux, centos, routing, ping, router

for school we have to do a linux routing vm between 4 subnet but the routing only works in one way. Let me explain, here is a schematic:

[image]
The router in the center is a CentOS 7 fully up-to-date with 4 nic, each one in a different subnet: 
        10.1.21.151/24 (top) -> lan of client pc and esxi server.
       200.200.0.254/24 (left) -> lan of a first windowsServer2016 AD/Exchange
        200.200.1.254/24 (bottom) -> lan of a nagios server
       200.200.2.254/24 (right) -> lan of a second windowsServer2016 AD/Exchange
The default gateway is 10.1.21.254/24

After enabling ip forwarding in centOS, I can access the nagios web interface from my client so the routing in that way is ok.

But with the nagios server, when i try to quit his subnet and ping my client, esxi, windowsServer1 or 2 -> nothing

Since the router has access to all subnet directly, i did not create any static route. Am i wrong ?

I think it isn't a routing problem but a "software" problem... Firewalld and NetworkManager are disabled.

## Update:

ip route list -> 
default via 10.1.21.254 dev ens13  proto static  metric 100  
10.1.21.0/24 dev ens13  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.21.151 
200.200.0.0/24 dev ens14 proto kernel scope link src 200.200.0.254
200.200.1.0/24 dev ens15 proto kernel scope link src 200.200.1.254
200.200.2.0/24 dev ens16 proto kernel scope link src 200.200.2.254

Comment: Did you modify any other kernel parameters for network traffic handling, routing, forwarding, etc?

Comment: no, each time i've tried a fix, i rollback to a snapshot of a clean install

Comment: Okay, good. You need to specify the `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` kernel parameter, as I'm sure you know. There are others that may or may not impact this setup, but most can probably be safely ignored.

Comment: It may also be helpful to look at the Cent7 routing table. `netstat -nr`

Comment: don't have the netstat command and we can't have internet right now so here is the output of ip route list above.

Comment: Is your CentOS box the default gateway for every machine you are trying to reach?

Comment: try the command `route -n` that show the routing information a bit more comprehensive.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot specify a gateway address for an interface that is not in the local network (its broadcast domain). E.G. 10.0.0.0/24 would contain all IPs from 10.0.0.1 through 10.0.0.254. If your system was assigned 10.0.0.15, it can only talk directly to 10.0.0.1 through 10.0.0.254.

When it needs to talk to an address outside the local network, one of the 253 others must forward the traffic. Specifying a gateway address is how your system knows WHICH of the other IPs will forward traffic for it (this is a very basic description, btw.)

From your example, each system (AD1, AD2, Nagios, etc.) should use the IP address from the Cent7 on its own network as its gateway setting. So, the gateway is going to be different for each of those systems...

AD1 should have a gateway of 200.200.0.254 ...

(ifcfg file entries)

```
IPADDR=200.200.0.x (IP of AD1)
PREFIX=24
GATEWAY=200.200.0.254
```

Comment: Yes that's what i did. If not i would not be able to access my nagios server from outside or even ping it.